# Search many arrays and objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have an array with many objects, all those objects have maybe arrays and objects, so this similar tree continuese, and I want to do a search that searches all values on all those arrays and objects and returns back.

Here is the function I have but doesn't work And I think it works only with the first object but this still is not working.

Here is the function I do have (its broken):

```
const findIn = (arr, query) => {
        let queryFormatted = query.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ' ');
        return arr.filter((obj) =>
          Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
              return obj[key]
                .toLowerCase()
                .replace(/\s/g, ' ')
                .includes(queryFormatted);
            }
            return false;
          })
        );
      };
```

Sample of Data (that needs to be searched):

[image: for example this to be searched]:

Comment: You're going to need recursion, but without a sample of your input/output we can't really help.

Comment: Please try to add an `else` part to the `if` condition to handle what needs to be done when `typeof` is not `'string'`. For example: `else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {.....doSomethingForArray()}`.

Comment: @jsN00b can you share an code example and explain

Comment: @Andy here we go, check it now

Comment: From the question: _an array with many objects_. On the attached image, would you please clarify which is this array? I count 3 empty arrays and one non-empty array that has one visible object. Also, I think @Andy may appreciate, as much as I do, that the data was not an image - but something which can be copy-pasted to be used on a code snippet to test.

Comment: @jsN00b yes they are filled for example with other objects that have string to search in

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and you want to check whether any nested string is a substring of your query, returning true or false, here is a solution:

```
const findIn = (elem, query) => {
query = query.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
if (!(elem instanceof Object)){
    if (typeof elem == "string"){
        return elem.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'').includes(query);
    }
    return false
}
if (Array.isArray(elem)){
    for (const nested of elem){
        if (findIn(nested,query)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
for (const nested of Object.values(elem)){
    if (findIn(nested,query)){
            return true;
        }
}
return false;
```

}

Note that this might not work in some specific cases but should be enough if you are parsing json into a js object and then calling the function.

Comment: I want to return that specifc object in case it has something.

Comment: I would like you to update and return the result/s that is found.